# Newton JSON deserialize to an object

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

I have a JSON as below I am trying to deserialize it into a C# object with following code but it always converts to null. How can i convert it using Newton JSON:

JSON:

```
{
    "details": {
        "MUMBAI": {
            "car": [
                {
                    "id": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "id": "local_taxi",
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum",
                    "sub_text": "Lorem ipsum"
                },
                {
                    "id": "delivery"
                }
            ]
        },
        "DELHI": {
            "car": [
                {
                    "id": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "id": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "id": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "category_id": "delivery"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
public class RootObject
{
public Detail detail{get; set;}
}

public class Detail 
{
public Dictionary<string, Car> CarLst{get; set;}
}

public class Car
{
 public string id{get; set;}
 public string text{get; set;}
 public string sub_text{get; set;}
}
```

C# code to deseralize:

```
responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Do you control the generated JSON or does this come from a 3rd Party API?

Comment: Its a third party API. I don't control it

Comment: Then you will have a problem using this JSON properly because MUMBAI and DELHI are seperate objects, they are not an array in the given JSOn, meaning you have to have a property for each (assuming) city that might be inside that JSON. Are you sure that is the correct JSON as what they are returning it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there can be any string value besides `MUMBAI` and `DELHI` at the second level of the json, you need to change `details` property type to `Dictionary<string, Cars>` where `Cars` is a class that contains a `List<Car>` property. Change your class definitions to the following

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Cars> details { get; set; }
}

public class Cars
{
    public List<Car> Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string sub_text { get; set; }
    public string category_id { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize the json to an instance of `RootObject` using the following code

```
var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse);
```

You can enumerate through the nested properties of `responseData` to get the properties of the cars. For example if we use the above json, `responseData.details["MUMBAI"].Car[0].id` will return `"ABC"` and `responseData.details["DELHI"].Car[3].category_id` will return `"delivery"`.

#### Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dIYHNB

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `s`

This should make it work

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Detail details{get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first reason why your `responseData` is `null`, as mentioned by the other answer is because our property inside the `RootObject` class is spelled incorrectly when compared to the given JSON.

Even if you fix that, you will still have `null` details because the next level inside the JSON is **not an array**, they are just additionally nested objects. So you cannot try and convert them into a `Dictionary<string, Car>`.

The JSON that you have is also a bit weird. According to its structure you will need to have a specific property for every (assumed) city that might be returned in the JSON, which doesn't make the handling of the JSON very dynamic.

Now to get the **given** JSON into a usable class data structure, you will need something that looks like the below class definitions. But as mentioned, this is not very extensible and will be very very heavy maintenance.

```
public class RootObject
{
  public Detail details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName="MUMBAI")]
  public City Mumbai { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DELHI")]
  public City Delhi { get; set; }

  // Add more of the above property definitions for each individual city that might be inside the returned JSON,
  // which is a very bad design. (Example city of Rohtak)
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ROHTAK")]
  public City Rohtak { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
  public List<Car> car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string text { get; set; }
  public string sub_text { get; set; }
  public string category_id { get; set; }
  // Might need to add additional possible properties here
}
```

Additional information as to how to use the `JsonProperty` and other Newtonsoft.Json feature can be found in their documentation pages [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)